# set_value function is not working in codeIgniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have to set/display the value in form fields during form_validation in codeIgniter but data is not set/displaying by using set_value function.

Here is my code,

view page -

**login_form.php**

```
<?= form_open('admin/login');?>

      <?= form_label('Username','username'); ?>
        <?= form_input(['id'=>"username", 'placeholder'=>"Username", "name"=>"username", 'value'=>set_value('username')]); ?><br>
        <?= form_error('username'); ?>
        <br>
      <?= form_label('Password', 'Password'); ?>
        <?= form_password(["id"=>"password", "placeholder"=>"Password", 
        "name"=>"pass", "value"=>set_value('pass')]); ?>
        <?= form_error('pass') ?>
        <br>
        <?php echo form_submit(['value'=>'Login']); ?>

<?= form_close(); ?>
```

Controller -

**admin.php**

```
public function login(){

            $this->load->library('form_validation');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'User Name', 'required|alpha|trim');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('pass', 'Password', 'required');

                if($this->form_validation->run()):
                    echo "Validation Success";
                    else:

                    $this->load->view('login_form']);

                endif;
        }
```

Please help and give suggestion regarding this.

Comment: what are values that you to set?and from where values are coming?

Comment: I have two fields username and password, when I write some data in username field and left blank password field , after submitting form error shows but the data which I had type in username field is not displaying in username field, its auto reset. I have to keep the username

Comment: just set `'value'=>'your value'`..like this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you not autoload  Form helper add

```
$this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
```

and add validation_errors before your form_open

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
```

for more datails check [Codeigniter Validation Form](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
   if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) { 
            echo "Validation Success";
                    else:

                    $this->load->view('login_form']);

                endif;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned you in comment.Just set value on your field like this..

```
<?= form_input(['id'=>"username", 'placeholder'=>"Username", "name"=>"username", 'value'=>'Sandeep']); ?><br>
```

Then it Will create a input field with value `Sandeep`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem solved when I added the 'form' in the helper

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('form');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably redirecting when validation fails, you need to load the form again.